# How to have Options with OR relations between 2 arguments

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-parser

I have a very basic question, below is my Options class. I need to establish an OR relation between j and f flags i.e anyone should be mandatory to be passed.

```
        [Option('j', "jsonfile", Required = true, HelpText = "Path to json file")]
        public string JsonFilePath { get; set; }

        [Option('f', "jsonfolder", Required = true, HelpText = "Path to json directory")]
        public string JsonFolder { get; set; }

        [Option('t', "targetpath", Required = true, HelpText = "Target folder")]
        public string TargetFolder { get; set; }
```

Here what I need is, if **j** is not passed in the argument then **f** should be mandatory to pass or if **f** is not passed in the argument then **j** should be mandatory to pass. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Is that [System.CommandLine](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api)?

Comment: its CommandLineParser https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline. But if you know how to achive that in System.CommandLine, I can try it.

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I've added the appropriate tag to your question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Group does the trick for you.

```
        [Option('j', "jsonfile", Group= "json", HelpText = "Path to json file")]
        public string JsonFilePath { get; set; }

        [Option('f', "jsonfolder", Group= "json", HelpText = "Path to json directory")]
        public string JsonFolder { get; set; }

        [Option('t', "targetpath", Required = true, HelpText = "Target folder")]
        public string TargetFolder { get; set; }
```